# how to solve multiple math model using CPLEX concert in one code file?

Tags: c++, cplex

it might be an easy question but I have never done it. I have two different math model codes in C++ and solved with CPLEX concert in two different code files. basically, these two codes are two subroutines which after solving the models, store the desired results in two 3 dimensional vectors. these two vectors will be used to make initial feasible solutions for the main heuristic algorithm. my question is how to solve both models in one code file to get these two vectors and use them for the next steps?

my initial thought is when I define the model, they can be numbered like:
for the first model:

```
    //building the model in CPLEX 
    IloEnv env1;

    //Construct Model 
    IloModel mod1(env);
```

and for the second model:

```
    //bilding the model in CPLEX 
    IloEnv env2;

    //Construct Model 
    IloModel mod2(env);
```

Comment: So, did you try to create a single C++ source file that includes creating and solving those two separate models? Did it work or not? If it didn't work, what went wrong? Also note that they don't have to be in the same source code file in order to be able to combine their results into a single array of values to warm-start the main model.

Comment: yes i just tried and after working on it for a day it worked

Answer (score 0):

to use the solution of the first model in the second model you could use [warmstart](https://medium.com/@AlainChabrier/warm-start-optimization-ac73eef189e9).

Let me quote documentation:

> There is no method to create a MIP start from a multidimensionalarray
> of variables. In order to create a MIP start from amultidimensional
> array of variables, you first must copy all thosevariables into a flat
> array. The following sample assumes a matrixof m by n dimensions with
> the starting value for x[i][j] in start[i][j].

```
 IloNumVarArray startVar(env);
 IloNumArray startVal(env);
 for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
     for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
         startVar.add(x[i][j]);
         startVal.add(start[i][j]);
     }
 cplex.addMIPStart(startVar, startVal);
 startVal.end();
 startVar.end();
```

Comment: the solutions of the two models are not related to each other. but both solutions will be used in the main algorithm to solve the main heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought was correct and it worked. the only thing I need to add is since there are two objectives, the IloObjective needs to have different names too.

Comment: A big issue for many people is that "CPLEX" tends to take on a huge role in peoples' minds. Remember that it is just software - in practice it is much easier to use as a tool than people expect.